# JCraft Jsch returns nothing while command works in a regular terminal

Tags: java, bufferedreader, jsch

All I am trying to do with jsch is execute

```
stat -c %s /directory/file.ext
```

...and it does work as expected from the command line. Now I know all of my ssh/reader/jsch code works just fine because I use a series of commands using the exact same code to gather the directory and the files after searching out things with the proper .ext.

In fact we are using the JCraft stuff for various other things for another test tool we are building. I can do ls, cd, find, grep, echo, etc. No problem. However as soon as I started doing stat it popped up. Now I am using

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

...so I thought maybe stat by default doesn't have a newline character for the readline, however, it is not being hung on the readline() method which would happen if no newline was present.

All the SSH connection stuff is working, no exceptions, no anything. It connects, executes the command, and just returns nothing.

```
cExec.setCommand(command);
InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
cExec.connect( timeoutInSecs * 1000 );  
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(commandOutput, "UTF-8") );      
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Where channel is a jcraft object that is part of its library.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code sample that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Like I said, I highly doubt my code is at fault considering it works for so many other commands.